# How can I use different arrays for different sections in a table view?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to create a table view that uses different arrays for data for each section. But, I am not sure how to access the section number to create conditionals to set the data for each section. Please let me know if my explanation if confusing and I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me. The code is below.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

struct PlasticCellData {
    let image: UIImage?
    let message: String?
}
struct PlasticAlphaHeader {
    let label: String?
}

class PlasticMaterial: UITableViewController {

    var rowHeight: CGFloat = 50
    var headerheight: CGFloat = 100
    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?

    var alphaHeaderArray = [PlasticAlphaHeader]()
    var aData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var bData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var cData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var dData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var eData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var fData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var gData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var hData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var iData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var jData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var kData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var lData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var mData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var nData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var oData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var pData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var qData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var rData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var sData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var tData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var uData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var vData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var wData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var xData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var yData = [PlasticCellData]()
    var zData = [PlasticCellData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupNavBar()
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        alphaHeaderArray =
            [PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "A"), PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "B"),
            PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "C"), PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "D"),
            PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "E"), PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "F"),
            PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "G"), PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "H"),
            PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "I"), PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "J"),
            PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "K"), PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "L"),
            PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "M"), PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "N"),
            PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "O"), PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "P"),
            PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "Q"), PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "R"),
            PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "S"), PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "T"),
            PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "U"), PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "V"),
            PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "W"), PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "X"),
            PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "Y"), PlasticAlphaHeader.init(label: "Z")]


        db.collection("plastic").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {

            }
            else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let firstLetter = name.prefix(1)
                    if firstLetter == "A" {
                        self.aData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "B" {
                        self.bData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "C" {
                        self.cData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "D" {
                        self.dData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "E" {
                        self.eData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "F" {
                        self.fData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "G" {
                        self.gData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "H" {
                        self.hData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "I" {
                        self.iData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "J" {
                        self.jData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "K" {
                        self.kData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "L" {
                        self.lData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "M" {
                        self.mData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "N" {
                        self.nData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "O" {
                        self.oData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "P" {
                        self.pData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "Q" {
                        self.qData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "R" {
                        self.rData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "S" {
                        self.sData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "T" {
                        self.tData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "U" {
                        self.uData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "V" {
                        self.vData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "W" {
                        self.wData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "X" {
                        self.xData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else if firstLetter == "Y" {
                        self.yData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    else {
                        self.zData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }

        self.tableView.register(ItemCustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "custom")
    }

    func setupNavBar() {
        navigationItem.title = "Select Item"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let alphaHeader = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AlphaHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! AlphaHeaderView

        alphaHeader.headerLabel.text = alphaHeaderArray[section].label
        return alphaHeader
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return headerheight
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custom") as! ItemCustomCell
        cell.itemImage = aData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = aData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = bData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = bData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = cData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = cData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = dData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = dData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = eData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = eData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = fData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = fData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = gData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = gData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = hData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = hData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = iData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = iData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = jData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = jData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = kData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = kData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = lData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = lData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = mData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = mData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = nData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = nData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = oData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = oData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = pData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = pData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = qData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = qData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = rData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = rData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = sData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = sData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = tData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = tData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = uData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = uData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = vData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = vData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = wData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = wData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = xData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = xData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = yData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = yData[indexPath.row].message
        cell.itemImage = zData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.message = zData[indexPath.row].message

        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return rowHeight
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 26
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return aData.count
        }
        if section == 1 {
            return bData.count
        }
        if section == 2 {
            return cData.count
        }
        if section == 3 {
            return dData.count
        }
        if section == 4 {
            return eData.count
        }
        if section == 5 {
            return fData.count
        }
        if section == 6 {
            return gData.count
        }
        if section == 7 {
            return hData.count
        }
        if section == 8 {
            return iData.count
        }
        if section == 9 {
            return jData.count
        }
        if section == 10 {
            return kData.count
        }
        if section == 11 {
            return lData.count
        }
        if section == 12 {
            return mData.count
        }
        if section == 13 {
            return nData.count
        }
        if section == 14 {
            return oData.count
        }
        if section == 15 {
            return pData.count
        }
        if section == 16 {
            return qData.count
        }
        if section == 17 {
            return rData.count
        }
        if section == 18{
            return sData.count
        }
        if section == 19 {
            return tData.count
        }
        if section == 20 {
            return uData.count
        }
        if section == 21 {
            return vData.count
        }
        if section == 22 {
            return wData.count
        }
        if section == 23 {
            return xData.count
        }
        if section == 24 {
            return yData.count
        }
        return zData.count
    }
}
```

Comment: What about a dictionary with a key for each section?

Comment: I am sorry. I am a beginner developer and do not know what a dictionary is. The solution below seems to be working for me. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You seriously need to sit down and learn swift properly before you continue with your project, not only about dictionaries but also about the rest of the language. Your solution looks very complicated and chances are that you can store and access your date in a more efficient way and with less code once you get a better understanding of the language. May I suggest the online book [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) but also looking at on-line tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the cellForRowAt function try to choose the array based on the section, like so:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custom") as! ItemCustomCell
        switch indexPath.section {
             case 0:
                  cell.itemImage = aData[indexPath.row].image
                  cell.message = aData[indexPath.row].message
             case 1:
                  cell.itemImage = bData[indexPath.row].image
                  cell.message = bData[indexPath.row].message
             //(...make one for each letter case until Z...)
             default:
                  cell.itemImage = zData[indexPath.row].image
                  cell.message = zData[indexPath.row].message
        }
        return cell
}
```

That works for your data structure, ideally though you should use a two-dimensional array, with the first dimension representing the letters and the second dimension representing the data of each letter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, however if one of the arrays has multiple values, the table view only shows one of them. Does this have something to do with the switch statements or some other error I have made elsewhere. Thanks again!!!

Comment: I think you're filling the data arrays incorrectly. It seems that inside the loop ````for document in snapshot!.documents```` you're rewriting each array with the latest document data instead of adding the data to the preexisting array. Try doing ````self.aData.append(PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name))```` instead of ````self.aData = [PlasticCellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlasticSilverware"), message: name)]````